# Column and grid system in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, grid, frontend

I'm new in Angular and Bootsrap 4, and I'm having trouble setting up the layout for a dashboard I'm currently working on. I have a series of cards that need to be arranged in a particular way, as follows:

[image]

I have a row, in which I have put a col-12 div, and inside I have placed all the cards (1,2 and 3 are static content, the others are loaded with a ngFor, from a list that comes from the database).

The problem with this is that since card 1's has double height relative to all the others, cols for 2 and 3 are the same height as the col for card one. The result is as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this using my approach, say, having the extra empty space in the colums for the cards 2 and 3 taken away, and place the other cards in there? Or should I use a completely different approach?
**edit:** Here's the code I've used.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="double-card-col">
                            <app-tool-card-double-1></app-tool-card-double-1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cards">
                            <tool-card-2></tool-card-2>
                            <tool-card-3></tool-card-3>
                        </div>
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let tool of tools; trackBy: trackBy">
                            <tool-card></tool-card>
                        </ng-container>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: has you take a look to the differents cards layout? I think that card-columns can be closer to your requeriments: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#card-columns

Comment: Have you looked into the HTML 5 grid, it allows for easily creating columns and rows.

Comment: I have used @Eliseo 's answer, but some elements go to the upside of the cards, and come all the way around to the bottom of the card-columns div. Any idea what could be causing this? Display: insline-block it's not helping.

Comment: Ended up using the grid system, card-columns turned out to be a little too wonky for what I needed. Thanks guys.

Comment: The short of it is you're not quite thinking in grid system yet. Two rows: A, containing 1-5, and B containing 6.  In Row A, two columns: a width=4 column for 1, and width=8 column for 2-5. Within that column, declare two rows, each with 2 columns, for 2 3, and 4 5 respectively. That should be everything.